# dict is not callable in python-kwargs error

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I have the following code which reads from a yaml :

```
if 'parameters' in options:
    for name, parameter_options in options['parameters'].items():
        make_parameters = injector.parameters()
        print parameter_options
        parameter_injected = make_parameters(**parameter_options)
        parameters = cft.add_parameters()
        parameters(key, **parameter_injected)
```

which gives me the error :

> ```
> parameter_injected = make_parameters(**parameter_options) TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
> ```

parameter_options is a dictionary as read from yaml and printed out :

```
{'constraint_description': 'Malformed input-Parameter MyParameter must only contain upper and lower case letters', 'min_length': 12, 'description': 'to do some stuff', 'default': '10.201.22.33', 'max_value': 34, 'min_value': 12, 'allowed_values': ['sdd', 'asas'], 'max_length': 23, 'allowed_pattern': '[A-Za-z0-9]+', 'no_echo': True, 'type': 'String'}
```

So when I do **parameter_options shouldn't that just convert the dict to charges?

Comment: Show the full traceback and the contents of `make_parameters`. And tag your question **either** Python 2.7 or Python 3.x unless you are genuinely writing cross-version code and using both. (I don't think you are given that you're not using `from __future__ import print_function`.)

Comment: parameters(key, **parameter_injected)  => parameters.update(keys , parameter_injected) ? is parameters  a dict ?

Comment: @Scooby What are you expecting that line to do? The issue is that make_parameters is a dict, and you are trying to call it as a function.

Comment: It seems like `injector.parameters()` is returning a dict, which you're trying to call like a function. What is `make_parameters` supposed to be?

Comment: my bad, that was a brain fart. Corrected it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, corrected my code to :

```
if 'parameters' in options:
    for name, parameter_options in options['parameters'].items():
        parameter_injected = injector.parameters(**parameter_options)
        parameters = cft.add_parameters(name, **parameter_injected)
```